# SQL Server 2012 enterprise installation for datawarehouse

Tags: installation, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

I am taking a course related to datawarehousing on SQL Server (by Martin Guidry at lynda.com). He is using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition for the demo.

Since this edition is supported only on servers like Microsoft SQL Server 2008, he suggests that any edition of SQL Server with database engine and SSIS can serve the purpose. I have compared the features supported by all editions at the link below, but I am still not sure which one to install..

link-https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Data_warehouse

If anyone of you have worked on D/W, please suggest which edition to install and from where to download for learning purpose..

Answer (score 0):

Before beginning, you should check that minimum hardware and software requirements to install and run SQL Server 2012 have been met. For operating system and hardware requirements, visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx.

[image: Features]

This will install the Database Engine Services, Analysis Services, Reporting Services, and a number of shared features including SQL Server Books Online. Since your taking a course and gaining all the knowledge, i would recommend (if you have the space) to install it all because eventually you will hit on every feature if not in this course, but future courses.

Good Luck!!